# Elasticsearch 5.5 - Error when using custom logs directory: Unable to create logger at ''

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, environment-variables

I try to install elasticsearch as Windows service. I set the environment variables to change the data and logs path with DATA_DIR and LOG_DIR.

If the LOG_DIR is not created yet, and it is only 1 level, the directory will be created (as expected).
The problem is when I specify LOG_DIR with nested directory and the directory doesn’t exist yet, it will throw error:

```
Unable to create logger at ''
```

For example:

```
LOG_DIR=D:/test/logs
```

If this location doesn’t exist, the error will occur.

Is there any way to tell ES to create the directory recursively?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `logs` directory should be created automatically, but Elasticsearch will not create directories recursively, thats has to be done by the user.